# Find count of read and unread message in single query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `Messages` in SQL Server 2012.
There are `three columns` in table

```
ID which is an identity column, 
MessageID (int) which is a foreign key to other table and 
IsRead field which is a bit not null column.
```

At a given point of time table can contain huge number of records with `IsRead` column value either `1 or 0`.
I want to write a single query in which I find count of read and unread messages in two separate columns.
I am trying to use new windows function introduced in SQL Server 2012 for efficiency.
How can I do it ?

Comment: Window functions as such where introduced in 2005. Why would you want to use them here?

Comment: Also please correct either "two columns" or the table definition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please check whether this helps.

```
SELECT 
    IsRead, 
    COUNT(*) ReadCount 
FROM 
    YourTable 
GROUP BY IsRead
```

Or you can select in two columns like:

```
SELECT  SUM(IsRead - 0) AS ReadCount,
        SUM(1 - IsRead) AS UnreadCount
FROM    YourTable
```

Comment: Second method really helped me

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN isRead = 1 THEN 1 END) AS read,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN isRead = 0 THEN 1 END) AS unread
FROM    mytable
```

Answer (score 1):

The query mentioned by **@Quassnoi** is simple .............

Here one more method is there you can get your solution

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(isRead) FROM [mytable] WHERE isRead = 1) AS READDATA,
(SELECT COUNT(isRead) FROM [mytable] WHERE isRead = 0) AS UNREADDATA
```

Answer (score -1):

select IsRead, count(*) from Messages Group by IsRead
But output will be 2 rows.